# splitting an array where it meets the peak values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

hope doing well.
I have an extremely big numpy array and want to split it into several ones. My array has three columns and I want to split it where the all the columns are reaching their maximum values:

```
array = [[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 5],
         [10, 5, 10],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [5, 5, 15],
         [10, 8, 20],
         [2, 0, 0],
         [10, 10, 12],
         [1, 2, 0],
         [2, 5, 9]]
```

Now, I want to split it into four array:

```
sub_array_1=[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 5],
         [10, 5, 10]]
sub_array_2=[[1, 1, 1],
         [5, 5, 15],
         [10, 8, 20]]
sub_array_3=[[2, 0, 0],
         [10, 10, 12]]
sub_array_4=[[1, 2, 0],
         [2, 5, 9]]
```

I tried to it in a for loop having if statements saying that give me an array when each element of my input is bigger than the element stored in the both upper and lower rows. And I also should figure out the last row:

```
import numpy as np    
sub_array_1=np.array([])
    for i in array:
        if array[i,:]>array[i+1,:] and array[i,:]>array[i+1,:]:
            vert_1=np.append(sub_array_1,array[0:i,:])
```

My code doesn't work, but it simply shows my idea.
I am quite new in Python and I could not find the way to write my idea as a code. So, I appreciate any help and contribution.
Cheers,
Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, one way using `numpy.diff` with `numpy.array_split`:

```
indices = np.argwhere(np.all(np.diff(array, axis=0) < 0, axis=1))
np.array_split(array, indices.ravel()+1, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[array([[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  5],
        [10,  5, 10]]),
 array([[ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 5,  5, 15],
        [10,  8, 20]]),
 array([[ 2,  0,  0],
        [10, 10, 12]]),
 array([[1, 2, 0],
        [2, 5, 9]])]
```

- `np.all` and `np.diff` find a row where all elements of the row as a negative difference with a next row (i.e. where the peak ends)
- `np.array_split` will then split the given array based on the locations of the peak found.

Comment: Dear @Chris, your solution is fantastic and efficient. Just another question: How can I extract the arrays from this resulted list? Is there a way to save them in the way I want, I mean like four separate arrays. thanks again for your help

Comment: @Ali_d As Best way would be to create a `dict`: `{"sub_array_%s" % n: v for n, v in enumerate(new_arrays, 1)}` where `new_arrays` are that list containing the split arrays ;).

Comment: Thanks for being that much helpful. Your hints are truly efficient. I tried to export sub_array from each dictionary but I couldn't handle it. In fact, I want to save each key (sub_arrays) and its value (the numpy array). I tried a for loop but it didn't work. In some cases I have tens of sub_arrays and it is pretty time consuming to export them manually. I want to find a way to keep each sub_array and its related data as a separate array.